# How can I resolve these errors when updating the module?

Tags: commerce, console

I want to update Drupal Commerce to 8.x-2.0-beta7 from a clean, Composer-based installation of 8.x-2.0-beta6, following the documentation on http://docs.drupalcommerce.org/v2/getting-started/update.html.

I noticed that `composer update drupal/commerce --with-dependencies` did not update drupal/core. This surprises me. Isn't drupal/core a dependency? Anyway, says it's white-listed so I then ran `composer update drupal/core`.

Now I am hitting a problem with updates.

> drupal update:debug
>
> Fatal error: Cannot use Drupal\Console\Core\Bootstrap\DrupalConsoleCore 
>       as DrupalConsoleCore because the name is already in use 
>       in/pathto/commerce8/vendor/drupal/console/src/Bootstrap/Drupal.php on 
>       line 11

> drupal update:execute
>
> Fatal error: Cannot use Drupal\Console\Core\Bootstrap\DrupalConsoleCore 
>       as DrupalConsoleCore because the name is already in use in 
>       /pathto/commerce8/vendor/drupal/console/src/Bootstrap/Drupal.php on 
>       line 11

I have since run update.php, but the Composer errors persist.

I am learning about Composer, and I don't know yet anything about Drupal Console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: These are Drupal Console errors, not Composer errors, whole different program. Please update the question title.
Guessing that Drupal Console broke because you forgot to do --with-dependencies when you updated drupal core. You need "composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Drupal Console someone was installed improperly, based on the duplicate class name error.

Can you try removing the `/pathto/commerce8/vendor` directory. Then run `composer install` once more. That'll fixup all third party dependencies, hopefully resolve this.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I did what you suggested and found exactly the same errors after running both drupal update:debug and drupal update:execute. Could it be that I have Drupal Console installed (elsewhere) globally?

Comment: It is possible. See https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/issues/3181,